# Converting some classic ASP 3.0 code into C# language and ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp-classic

I need to convert some "Classic ASP 3.0" code into C# using ASP.NET:

```
Randomize()
intUP  = 9
intLow =  1

intRange = intUp - intLow 
intRandom = CInt ((intRange * Rnd()) + intLow)

Response.Write(intRandom & "<br /><br />")

for i = 1 to (num) + intRandom
   Response.Write(intRandom & "<br />")
next
```

And I have tried this code:

```
int count;
Random rnd;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rnd = new Random();
    count = GetRandomInt(1, 9);

                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                   Response.Write(count.ToString());
                }
}


protected int GetRandomInt(int min, int max)
{
    return rnd.Next(min, max);
}
```

But in Classic ASP 3.0, the maximum output is 9, but in C# and ASP.NET, it is much higher.

What am I missing?

What's wrong with this code?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the maximum number is lower in the C# code, but you are writing the numbers back to back so they are shown as one big number instead of separate numbers.

The `Random.Next` method returns a number that is at least as high as the first parameter, and lower than the second parameter. Calling `rnd.Next(1, 9)` will give you a number between 1 and 8.

You are loopin from zero and up to one less than the random number. When you write those number in the loop with nothing in between them, the output for the largest value would be:

```
01234567
```

where the original code would instead write this for the largest value:

```
9

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

To get a random number between `min` and `max`, add one to the `max`:

```
return rnd.Next(min, max + 1);
```

Loop from one instead of zero, include the end value, and put something in between the numbers:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
  Response.Write(count.ToString() + "<br />");
}
```

---

Note: The random calculation in the original code is actually incorrect, as it would generate the lowest and the highest value half as often as any of the other numbers. The correct implementation would be:

```
intRange = intUp - intLow + 1
intRandom = Int((intRange * Rnd()) + intLow)
```

The C# code mimics the correct implementation, not the incorrect one.